# MySQL: [Err] 1146 - Unknown error 1146

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.7.13. I'm getting above error if a table doesn't exist. Not only this whatever the error is I'm getting only 'unknown error'. Can any let me know that how to make MySQL to display actual error i.e. Table doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: You get that error doing what?

Comment: Hi, was trying to select some records from a table but I wrote the table name wrongly. In older versions it shows the ERROR message as Table doesn't exist but in this version it is only gives error code with unknown error.

Comment: Do you mean that the error message, as reported by server, does not include the actual error but "unknown error" and it isn't a problem in whatever client you use?

Comment: Yes, the error message, as reported by server, does not include the actual error but "unknown error".

Comment: It's possibly the issue described in [this answer to the same question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123205/2467) at DBAs sibling site.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue with a raw download binary.

Comes with this error when trying to run any `mysqld`:

```
[ERROR] Can't find error-message file
```

Solved it by specifying `--lc_messages_dir`.

Examples:

```
mysqld --console --datadir ~/.mysqldata --lc_messages_dir=$MYSQL_HOME/share/english --initialize-insecure 
mysqld --console --datadir ~/.mysqldata --lc_messages_dir=$MYSQL_HOME/share/english
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You should probably look if your table exist.
2. If you are inserting data from one table to another table with a statement like, Insert into table_A select * from table_B, in this if there is any column mismatch, you will encounter this error.

Comment: 2 reasons, one you must be  using community edition of workbench or your settings must be incorrect. update latest version of workbench or mysql IDE

Answer (score 0):

Following two steps will help you out:

1. if you have copied the mysql data , Go to the original directory xampp/mysql/data ( or whatever is relevant to your OS) , and copy all the files starting with word ib, like ib_logfil0 etc. and paste to the new directory.
2. Go to mysql command line, and run this command:

> mysql_upgrade